# Error "undefined variable at noteLine" in FLWOR expression when returning multiple nodes

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

I have a very strange problem with a FLWOR loop, that works one way but not another.  The goal is to take a string of any length, and break it into XML nodes that can only hold 80 chars each.  So, first whack, this works great:

```
    for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
    where $noteLine != ''

    return
    if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) < 80) then (
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>  
    ) else if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 160) then (
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>,
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>
    ) else if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 240) then (
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>,
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>,
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>
    ) else()
```

So, I get it in my head that this isn't very elegant.  I try to clean it up by moving the first element out of the if, since it should always get used, right?  Less code that way?  So here is what I tried:

```
for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
where $noteLine != ''

return

    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>, 
    if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 160) then (
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>
    ) else if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 240) then (
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>,
    <NTE>
        <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
        <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
    </NTE>
    ) else()
```

And the parser is now telling me "undefined variable at noteLine" pointing to the first "if" line. What am I missing here? (note that yes, I do have other ideas of how to clean this up even more, but this was the first simple step and when it failed miserably, I panicked).

**Solution (thanks to Jens Erat)**
The return block needs to be wrapped in parentheses in order to force it to evaluate fully on each iteration of the flwor loop.  Thusly:

```
for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
where $noteLine != ''

return
    (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>, 
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 160) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 240) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>,
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>WHI</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else()
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a minor syntax issue. You have to put parenthesis around the elements created in the `return` clause. To further explain the issue, I'm providing a similar, but simplified example:

```
for $i in 1 to 3
return
    <foo />,
    <bar />
```

You'd expect to get following result (the two elements repeated three times):

```
<foo/>
<bar/>
<foo/>
<bar/>
<foo/>
<bar/>
```

But instead, you get

```
<foo/>
<foo/>
<foo/>
<bar/>
```

This is because the query is actually evaluated as

```
(
  for $i in 1 to 3
  return
      <foo />
),
<bar />
```

In your code, you don't get unexpected output, but an error message. This is because `$noteLine` is not defined after the first comma `,`. You would get a similar error message for following query:

```
for $i in 1 to 3
return
    <foo>{ $i }</foo>,
    <bar>{ $i }</foo>
```

Here, `$i` is not bound for the `<bar/>` element, as the query is evaluated as

```
(
  for $i in 1 to 3
  return
      <foo>{ $i }</foo>
),
<bar>{ $i }</foo> (: obivously, $i is not defined here :)
```

Comment: So, the comma is acting differently when it's outside the if.  That makes sense.  However, what do I do to fix it, use parentheses instead of braces? Without the comma the code breaks at the if statement itself. The comma is needed (so I am led to believe) whenever I want more than one discrete node at the same level in a FLWOR.  I thought I understood the rules of braces vs parentheses but clearly I do not :-(

Comment: This is a question of operator precedence. If you only use the comma without any parenthesis, a sequence on the outermost possible layer is assumed. Using parenthesis, you can enforce the creation of a sequence (which then can hold multiple elements, separated by a comma each. Parenthesis have another meaning although they might seem similar as curly brackets in other languages, they construct result sets, and do not denote code blocks. Curly brackets in XQuery have a completely other meaning again, and cannot be used in this case.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for where parenthesis vs code brackets come into use in XQuery? My next step to improve the code is to use individual if statements for each step (> 80, >160, etc) instead of the big if-else/if-else to further reduce the code duplication, but the FLWOR loop doesn't allow more than one if in the return, and I also cannot put each if in code brackets (at least as a step by itself).

Comment: Sorry, I don´t really get your question. Forget about curly brackets, they're mostly used for defining XQuery statements inside XML elements (or other values). They do not have the same meaning like curly brackets in other languages, better consider them the `<?php` and `?>` in PHP (or similar constructs in other languages).

Comment: In a return, why can't I go straight into an if, and have more than one if in the return?  My parser rejects it in every case (regardless of parentheses placement) unless I put some node tags wrapping the outside of the if condition.

Comment: This seems like another, new question -- and comments are not really meant (and suitable) for whole questions. Better ask a new question instead, while providing a code example and description what exactly you're trying to do. If you add the [tag:xquery] tag, I'll be notified anyway, but feel free to leave a comment here linking to the new question.