# XQuery FLWOR return section code content with multiple if statements

Tags: xml, if-statement, xquery, flwor

I am trying to clean up some XQuery code and ran into another problem (last question was this one: [Error "undefined variable at noteLine" in FLWOR expression when returning multiple nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935080/error-undefined-variable-at-noteline-in-flwor-expression-when-returning-multip)).  I am further cleaning up the following working code, to minimize reuse:

```
    for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
    where $noteLine != ''

    return (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>, 
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80 and fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) <= 160) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>,
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else ()
    )
```

Now that I moved the first NTE out, I want to basically do the same with the rest (run an IF and only output another using exactly the code that's needed) so I pictured a solution like this:

```
    for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
    where $noteLine != ''

    return (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>, 
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else()
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else ()
    )
```

This fails in the parser with the error "Unexpected Token: ' (fn:string-len...'" pointing at the second if statement.  I have concluded that XQuery does not like recurring if sections unless they are within a node, like this:

```
    for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
    where $noteLine != ''

    return (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>, 
        <NTE>
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80) then (
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>,
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        ) else()
        </NTE>,
        <NTE>
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160) then (
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>,
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
        ) else ()
        </NTE>
    )
```

This is not workable, because I can't let any of those extra nodes get in the output if they are empty.  Is there a way in XQuery to achieve the desired output a similar way (I worked out a solution by putting some of the code into a local function but it is not as readable imo)?  And possibly as a follow up, why is XQuery so sensitive to multiple consecutive if statements?

**Solution (again thanks to Jens Erat)**

```
    for $noteLine in $noteLineArr
    where $noteLine != ''

    return (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 1, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>, 
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 80) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 81, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else(),
        if (fn:string-length(fn:normalize-space($noteLine)) > 160) then (
        <NTE>
            <NoteRefCd>BOL</NoteRefCd>
            <Descr>{fn:substring(fn:normalize-space($noteLine), 161, 80)}</Descr>
        </NTE>
        ) else()
    )
```

(Note: comma placement is appropriate after the first two "sections" of the return, the first NTE node and then after the if statement, not within the if statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XQuery is a functional programming language. Among other things, this means everything has an expression with a single, distinct return value. You can also have *multiple* statements returning something, but then you always have to wrap them in a sequence, which is an expression wrapping an arbitrary number of input expressions into one return value (the sequence).

### Explaining Expressions

To explain the issue with less boilerplate code, consider a small example like

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return $i
```

This obviously returns all numbers from one to ten. What if we only want to return the even numbers, using an if statement? The `if` statement is of the form `if (expression) then expression else expression`. Remember: every expression has to have a return value, this also applies to the `else` clause. In this case, we just have it return the empty sequence `()`, which in XQuery means "no value".

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return
  if ($i mod 2 eq 0)
  then $i
  else ()
```

### Having Multiple `if` Expressions

This works fine and returns all the even values. Now, lets consider we *also* want to print a string whenever a number can be divided by three. We cannot simply put this into the `else` clause, as for example `6` is both even *and* can be divided by three. We need to separate `if` clauses. This is also what you tried in your second code example.

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return
  if ($i mod 2 eq 0)
  then $i
  else (),
  if ($i mod 3 eq 0)
  then "three"
  else ()
```

This fails because `$i` is not defined in the second `if` clause. But why? Remember: Every expression is expected to have a single return value. Also the expression for the `return` statement, which is the `if then else` expression. So similar to your first question, the XQuery compiler considers this example to be

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return
  if ($i mod 2 eq 0)
  then $i
  else (),
if ($i mod 3 eq 0)
then "three"
else ()
```

which should make the problem more obvious. In the end, it is the same problem like in your original question, but with more complicated expressions. Both are of the form

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return
  expression1,
  expression2
```

having to be enclosed in a sequence if they should both belong to the return statement:

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return (
  expression1,
  expression2
)
```

With the expressions being elements/element constructors in your old question, and `if then else` expressions over here.

### The Solution for Multiple `if` Expressions

Again, you have to wrap them in a sequence:

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return (
  if ($i mod 2 eq 0)
  then $i
  else (),
  if ($i mod 3 eq 0)
  then "three"
  else ()
)
```

Now, the sequence is the single expression for the `return` statement, and has again two subexpressions containing the `if then else` code. This is also required when you're mixing different kinds of expressions, like in this example:

```
for $i in 1 to 10
return (
  if ($i mod 2 eq 0)
  then $i
  else (),
  <foo/>
)
```

Removing the sequence parenthesis will have the XQuery engine output the even numbers and then a single `<foo/>` element, instead of ten `<foo/>` elements -- one for each `$i`.

Comment: Wish I could give 10 upvotes.  I knew commas had to be used to separate nodes in the return but I never stopped to consider the if statement itself as a node (I tried putting a comma after each node inside the if statement to counter that, but my intuition was wrong and it ignored it.)

Comment: I think you've now got the point. Getting the functional paradigms right isn't easy if XQuery is the first functional programming language, don't worry. One last note: the `if/then/else` statement isn't really a node. Nodes are only those basic entities that also exist in XML -- namely the root/document node, elements, attributes, text, comments and processing instructions. Although the consequences are similar here (no matter whether returning multiple nodes or other statements, put them in a sequence).

Comment: It's the first functional language that I have had so little to start with, including the terminology.  Not that I should be doing all my learning from Google, but I would have hoped a search for "multiple if statements in flwor xquery" would have at least one relevant result in the top 20,  but none mentioned using a comma to separate multiple if statements.  Hopefully this question will make its way into the results.